# navigation drawer action bar depreciated

Tags: android, android-studio, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

Hey I am not sure what I am suppose to replace this with as I cannot find anything clear and simple... this is the code that shows up depreciated while using android studios navigation drawer template...

```
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
```

This is the code

```
public void restoreActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
    }
```

I tried incorporating a toolbar in the past but it let to a bunch of issues maybe I did it wrong...I am trying to replace `NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST` not `NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS` which can be found in that post